# Заполнения элементов массива 0 в c++

Tags: c++, массивы

Скажем есть переменная val, которому вводится какое то значения от пользователя(cin), и я хочу создать массив с этим val(то есть int ar[val]) и присвоить всем элементам массива 0, не зная какое значение в val.Думаю понятно объяснил, заранее спасибо за помощь

Comment: Отвечать не надо сам понял как сделать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так годится?

```
int * ar = new int[val]{};
```

Просто создавать массив

```
int ar[val];
```

с неизвестным во время компиляции значением `val` в С++ запрещено.

Comment: `int ar[val];` вообще-то разрешено, если `ar` - локальная переменная и компилятор поддерживает VLA (а я предполагаю, что все нормальные компиляторы это поддерживают).

Comment: @LShadow77 В стандарте о таком расширении, как и о понятии **нормальности** в применении к компилятору, ничего не говорится.

Comment: возможно. Но тем не менее это работает. А раз работает, то почему бы не использовать такую прекрасную возможность? Кстати, MS VC++ поддерживает VLA? MinGW, которым я привык пользоваться, поддерживает.

Comment: @LShadow77 MSVC не поддерживает.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Как так? Даже последней версии? Это печально. Вообще странно, почему VLA не желают внести в стандарт (могу предположить из-за того, что не все процессоры/контроллеры такое позволяют). Штука реально полезная.

Comment: @LShadow77 Не использовать, чтобы не приобретать плохие привычки :) Ну, и переносимость тоже вопрос, о котором неплохо бы помнить...

Comment: @Harry переносимость)) `#ifdef __GNUC__ int ar[val]; #else int* ar = new int[val]; #endif`. Но мысль ясна.

Comment: @LShadow77 *"почему VLA не желают внести в стандарт"* Это издевательство над системой типов. :/ С++ и так достаточно сложный, не хватало еще типов переменного размера.

Comment: @LShadow77 Да и вообще, я бы использовал - если уж так приспичило в стеке память выделить - вызов `alloca()`.